# Are com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange attributes broken?

Tags: java, com.sun.net.httpserver

First some (very basic) sample code to illustrate my problem:

```
final java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong previousId = new java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong();
final com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer server = com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create(new java.net.InetSocketAddress(8666), 0);
server.setExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
server.createContext("/", exchange -> {
  final long id = previousId.incrementAndGet();
  System.out.println(String.format("#%s: id attribute=%s", id, exchange.getAttribute("id")));
  exchange.setAttribute("id", id);
  while (true) {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(1_000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      return;
    }
    System.out.println(String.format("#%s: id attribute=%s", id, exchange.getAttribute("id")));
  }
});
server.start();
```

While running this program (on Java SE 1.8.0_171), if I make two consecutive requests to `http://localhost:8666`, I get the following log:

```
#1: id attribute=null
#1: id attribute=1
#1: id attribute=1
#2: id attribute=1
#1: id attribute=2
#2: id attribute=2
#1: id attribute=2
#2: id attribute=2
```

For request #1, the attribute is initially `null`, as expected. For request #2 though, the attribute is initially `1`, which seems to imply that the initial value is inherited from the other request. Worse, as you can see, changing the value to `2` for request #2 also changes the value to `2` for request #1. It seems that the attributes are shared between `HttpExchange` instances, which is not what I would expect.

Am I missing something or are `HttpExchange` attributes broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the source code](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/a4fb32538898/src/jdk.httpserver/share/classes/sun/net/httpserver/ExchangeImpl.java#l366), it’s perfectly clear that `HttpExchange` attributes are shared by all the instances on the same `HttpContext`. I find it misleading though that `setAttribute` and `getAttribute` methods are defined on `HttpExchange`. The [Javadoc](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/a4fb32538898/src/jdk.httpserver/share/classes/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpExchange.java#l219) doesn’t help either in my opinion:

> Filter modules may store arbitrary objects with HttpExchange instances as an out-of-band communication mechanism.

I have [sent an email to the net-dev mailing list](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/net-dev/2019-December/013418.html) and [filed a bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8235786). I will update this answer as soon as I get some news.